# How to post leaderboard in embed [discord.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a discord.js leveling system that stores peoples levels in a json file `database.json` like this: `{"626916199783071750":{"xp":54,"level":14}`I am sorting everyone's levels using this code:

```
members.sort(function(a, b) {
  const keyA = a[Object.keys(a)[0]].level,
        keyB = b[Object.keys(a)[0]].level;
  // Compare
  // (swap -1 and 1 to change sort order)
  if(keyA < keyB) return -1;
  if(keyA > keyB) return 1;
  return 0;
});
console.log(members);
```

(members is being defined with `const members = [require("./database.json")];`)
I am able to log it fine and it is in the correct order but I was wondering how I would send that in an embed as this code was not working:

```
      let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor(0x4286f4)
      .addField('Level:', members)
      member.channel.send(embed);
```

This was giving me an embed with just undefined as a field.
For reference i am using discord.js v12+

Comment: It should be `new Discord.MessageEmbed()` because you are using v12 of Discord.js

Comment: now im getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined`

Comment: i think it is being caused somewhere else please check the line number where the error is being caused.

Comment: I don't believe discord.js allows you to directly set embed fields or message content to arrays/objects. You would need to convert the array into a string before adding it to the field of the embed. As for the `Cannot read property 'client' of undefined`, that error is unrelated to this issue and is somewhere else in your code entirely.

Comment: It says its happening on the line of code that is `let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After editing multiple times and talking with you below, I allow myself to make some changes to your bot's way of functioning.

### Data storage

First of all, the way you store data is kind of bad. JSON is a bad choice and is very annoying to use as a DB, but it remains an option. You should check out [`Quick.db`](https://quickdb.js.org/), which is excellent for beginners! On the other hand, you *always*, always, want to store documents in an array. Arrays are literally made for that. Here's some code to switch your current data to the new model. Don't forget to also update the other parts of your bot that store data so it matches the new shape. I don't want to make too many changes, but I'd like to add that storing the `level` is a bad idea, since it depends on `xp`. You should write a function that converts `xp` into `level` and use it, instead of storing `level`.

```js
// const fs = require("fs")
// const oldDb = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("database.json"))
const oldDb = {
  "626916199783071750": {
    "xp": 69,
    "level": 14
  },
  "579776588732956674": {
    "xp": 2,
    "level": 13
  },
  "784566696244674621": {
    "xp": 99,
    "level": 1
  },
  "495304082769051660": {
    "xp": 6,
    "level": 1
  },
  "752987763573391411": {
    "xp": 1,
    "level": 0
  }
}

let newDb = Object.keys(oldDb).map((id) =>
  ({
    id,
    xp: oldDb[id].xp,
    level: oldDb[id].level
  })
)

console.log(newDb)
// fs.writeFile("database.json", JSON.stringify(newDb), 'utf8')
```

#### Sorting by level

From that point, you'll be able to work in a much more efficient way. Since we've changed the bot's data model, I'll help you convert the sorting method into one that *actually* works.

```js
// const users = require("./database.json"), with the new data model this time
const users = [{
  id: "626916199783071750",
  level: 14,
  xp: 69
}, {
  id: "579776588732956674",
  level: 13,
  xp: 2
}, {
  id: "784566696244674621",
  level: 1,
  xp: 99
}, {
  id: "495304082769051660",
  level: 1,
  xp: 6
}, {
  id: "752987763573391411",
  level: 0,
  xp: 1
}]

const sortedUsers = users.sort((a, b) => (a.level > b.level) ? 1 : -1) // ternary operation, it's basically just a 'if'
console.log(sortedUsers)
```

### Post leaderboard

Ah, you did it! Now, here's my original answer... how to send all that data.
You'd need to add a field for each member. [`MessageEmbed#addFields()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addFields) is perfect here. The code below isn't tested.

```js
const maxNumberOfUsersToDisplay = 10;

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor(0x4286f4).addFields(
  sortedUsers.flatMap((userDoc, i) => {
    // flatMap will map and delete all the [] of the array
    if (!(i < maxNumberOfUsersToDisplay && i < 25)) return [];

    return {
      name: user.id, // Feel free to mess with the code and replace this with a mention/tag
      value: `Level ${user.level}`,
      inline: false, // default value, just to show you you can adjust this param to change the embed layout
    };
  })
);

message.channel.send(embed);
```

[`Array#flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) acts like a `.map()` and a `.flat()`, it's an obscure method that should be used more often : it can also be used as a `.map()` and a `.filter()`, as shown above.

Comment: here is a link to my database it should what you send still work?
https://sourceb.in/x4hsyLxeaf

Comment: Why do you use `sort` then? It's an object... Could you please give me what `console.log(members)` outputs?

Comment: the log gets me 
[Link to Image](https://ibb.co/JtxbHb2)

Comment: Okay. Why do you use `[require('database-file')]` ? What is the purpose of the `[]`? There's only 1 element in it, so the `sort` method does nothing.

Comment: if i dont't it gives me `TypeError: members.sort is not a function`

Comment: I edited the post. If you do things correctly, it should work, please ask me/edit your question if you have any other question!

Comment: (by the way, this `[]` is useless: it just puts your db in an array, and since it's the only element, sorting the elements will do absolutely nothing. You can test it if you want: `[db] === [db].sort()` will return `true`)

Comment: Will this code work with all the lines commented out? Also @a2br thank you so much for your time and help it really means the world to me!

Comment: The commented lines use fs. The first two add fs as a dependency and use it to get the DB from your JSON. I commented them because SO snippets do not support require(), so I hardcoded your DB instead (that's of course something you don't want to do). The last commented line writes the new content to the DB. Make sure you update the rest of your code before updating the way your DB stores data, it would create errors. I'd like to add that fs is better than require when it comes to opening JSON files, because it doesn't cache them.